# Action onclick of bar of nvd3-multi-bar-horizontal Polymer component

Tags: polymer, nvd3.js

I'm using nvd3-multi-bar-horizontal Polymer tag element for Graph plotting.
I could not find any option or attribute to add action like onclick on a bar.
Can anyone suggest any option? I know that it can be done using native nvd3 library. but as its a Polymer project, I have to use this Polymer component.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated nvd3-elements to bind all NVD3 events. Please use v0.21.0. You could create listeners for all NVD3 events. Please check [NVD3 documentation](http://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html) for events list of each chart.